# How to restore Terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I was continously having to paste in the following into each new Terminal session to access mysql command line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

I modified bashrc and pasted it into that file:

```
nano ~./bashrc
```

Now Terminal doesn't work anymore.

When I start a Terminal session, I get this output:

```
  [Restored Jul 19, 2017, 8:32:57 AM]
Last login: Tue Jul 18 17:49:29 on ttys000
  [Restored Jul 19, 2017, 8:35:09 AM]
Last login: Wed Jul 19 08:34:58 on console
Restored session: Wed Jul 19 08:33:16 MST 2017

[Process completed]
```

Before `[Process completed]` displays, there is some activity. I'm not sure what it is doing but I can tell there is activity by the flickering in the title bar. I see it going change from "Terminal" to "bash-" and back and forth. It take about a minute and then `[Process completed]` displays.

At this point, I can't type anything into Terminal. Every time I startup Terminal, it goes through the same cycle.

Any ideas how I can get it back in working order?

UPDATE:
I just discovered this: If I type in `ctrl-c`, I get the regular Terminal back and can type into it.

I also typed in `reset` and then `ctrl-j`. But it still goes through all that activity and I always have to type `ctrl-c` to get the regular Terminal before the activity finishes. Otherwise, the prompt is inactive and I can't do anything.

I can now `nano .bashrc`, the contents contain only my `export PATH` statement. Even though the mysql path is there, it still doesn't recognize `mysql -u root -p`.

Comment: Just added an UPDATE to the OP.

Comment: Please include the output of `echo "$PATH"` and `cat ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you can get to a prompt with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> suggests there's some hung task (possibly something waiting for input from stdin) being run from your `.bashrc`.

First, a debugging tip - if you can't start your terminal due to a bad `.bashrc` you can invoke `bash` with the `--noprofile --norc` flags, which will skip your personal config files. (how you actually start Bash without a terminal is OS-specific, but there's generally a way to start a program from the GUI; point is those are the flags you need). You can also edit your `.bashrc` from a GUI text editor, or temporarily rename it so it's not being loaded from a GUI file browser.

It's likely the `export` command isn't correct. The first thing I notice is that you haven't quoted the assignment, which could be a problem if there are any special characters (such as spaces) in your `PATH`. So try:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
```

Comment: I did put the path in quotes but that didn't help. I removed the above line, which was the only thing in that file. Still Terminal starts up the same way.

Comment: @4thSpace Please include the output of `echo "$PATH"` and `cat ~/.bashrc` in your question, then.

Comment: I found the issue. The problem was in `.bash_profile`. Where the above `export` should have been, it had this instead:  `source ~/.bash_profile`. I replaced it with the export and now everything works. Thanks.